# Unable to hook in between a user action and excel processing a standard button click event

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-addins, ribbonx

**What is needed:**
I need an Excel addin which can capture the click events of various Standard Command bar buttons on the Ribbon tabs. Also, once this is done the normal processing of the command button should proceed.

**Example :**
When I capture ribbon button click event, when the "Save" button is clicked , I should be able to
a) Do custom processing, display a message box or log this click event to a flat file **AND**
b) Let excel do the actual work of saving the worksheet

I have referred -

[Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb462633(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

[Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Although, am able to capture the standard button clicks am **not able to get both points a) and b) to work at the same time.**

**Ribbon1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <commands>
      <command idMso="FileSave" onAction="OnRibbonButtonClick" />
  </commands>
</customUI>
```

Ribbon1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

namespace ExcelAddIn
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Ribbon1 : Office.IRibbonExtensibility
    {
        private Office.IRibbonUI ribbon;

        public Ribbon1()
        {
        }

        #region IRibbonExtensibility Members

        public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID)
        {
            return GetResourceText("ExcelAddIn.Ribbon1.xml");
        }

        #endregion

        #region Ribbon Callbacks
        //Create callback methods here. For more information about adding callback methods, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=271226

        public void Ribbon_Load(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI)
        {
            this.ribbon = ribbonUI;
        }

        public void OnRibbonButtonClick(Office.IRibbonControl control, bool Cancel)
        //public void OnRibbonButtonClick(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {
            Globals.ThisAddIn.OnStandardRibbonCommand(control.Id);
            ribbon.Invalidate();
            Cancel = false;
        }           
        #endregion


        #region Helpers

        private static string GetResourceText(string resourceName)
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string[] resourceNames = asm.GetManifestResourceNames();
            for (int i = 0; i < resourceNames.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (string.Compare(resourceName, resourceNames[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                {
                    using (StreamReader resourceReader = new StreamReader(asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceNames[i])))
                    {
                        if (resourceReader != null)
                        {
                            return resourceReader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

With the above source code, I can capture the FileSave event, but the file does not get saved. i.e. the default Excel funtionality of saving the file does not happen.

**Am I missing something or this cannot be done?**

[Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon]
**Does this mean that the command is completely repurposed and the original purpose cannot be fulfilled?**

**Environment:**
Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2205 Build 16.0.15225.20172) 64-bit

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.11.7

VSTO version 10.0.60724

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repurposed callback should have the following signature:

```
C#: void OnAction(IRibbonControl control, ref bool CancelDefault)

VBA: Sub OnAction(control As IRibbonControl, byRef CancelDefault)

C++: HRESULT OnAction([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [in,out] VARIANT _BOOL *fCancelDefault)

Visual Basic: Sub OnAction(control As IRibbonControl, byRef CancelDefault)
```

It seems you need to use the following method instead:

```
public void OnRibbonButtonClick(Office.IRibbonControl control, ref bool Cancel)
{
    Debug.Print(control.Id);
    Cancel = false;
}
```

Comment: That worked, not sure how I missed the ref keyword, but it solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

After you process the repurposed button click event, you can simply call `Worksheet.Save`.

Or you can avoid repurposing and just handle `Wordsheet.BeforeSave`/`AfterSave` events.

Comment: That will work for a single or a handful of events, but I need to capture more than 100 events from different ribbon tabs, preferably using a single callback function. 
Basically, I just need to capture the ribbon button click events.

I am handling the Workbook and Worksheet events which satisy most of the use cases, but specifically I need to handle the ribbon button click events.

Comment: Just curious why you need to do that?

Comment: To analyze the activity a user does in Excel and improve, and make it efficient

Comment: If I were you, I'd rather use a Windows event hook to process mouse messages and Accessibility API to figure out where the user clicks

Comment: That is exactly the fallback I plan to use, but to use 2 separate programs for a single purpose is not a good idea. Hence looking for both (ribbon/keyboard events and Excel workbook/worksheet events) the functionality under a single roof.